# Remove xib file from view

Tags: iphone, ios, xib

I am loading a xib file from my viewcontroller which has a table view.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewView" owner:self options:nil])
    [self.newView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:self.newView];
```

The view is correctly loaded. 
On a button click in the newView I want to remove this view.

```
[self.newView removeFromSuperview];
```

The newView is removed. But the tableview behind it doesn't show anything. It just shows a transparent background. Cant find a way to sort it. Help needed

Comment: Why are you using [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow as parent view?
Do you have correct tableView's delegate and dataSource? Have you tried to refresh tableView by calling [tableView reloadData] after removing newView from parent?

Comment: I am new to objective c and iphone development. It seems I am doing things the wrong way. I have been using [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow throughout my project to load xib files.I dont understand the need to reload the table view data, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: So, are you sure about correct table view's delegate and dataSource?

Comment: It would automatically be self. Right? Could you explain a bit

Comment: I tried setting the delegate and datasource to self. It doesnt seem to work

Comment: A whole blank view. No tableview

Comment: I am just trying to add a subview to the current viewcontroller view. Am I making it complex. The problem is that when I am trying to remove the view, the viewcontroller view doesn't seem to exist

Comment: You did say that a whole blank view... it looks like it remove the tableview.

Comment: Yes. Removing the view I have added, I get a whole blank view with the  navigation bar. But doing as below, the table view is loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewView" owner:self options:nil];
[self.newView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[self.view addSubview:newView];
```

And I removed the view by

```
[self.newView removeFromSuperview];
```